# Two Checkboxes interfear with one-another in same form

Tags: php

i have two checkbox **$multID** and **$catID** wrapped in a form and whenever i select these two checkboxes they don't work properly,i need to check them equally for ot to work i.e i need to check 2-2,or 1-1 or 3-3 checkboxes of **$multID** and **$catID** repectively,if i check 3-2 or 1-3 box it won't work. what i meant is this -----> if i select TWO item from $multID and select ONE item from $catID it will INSERT just ONE item of $multiD bcos i select just one of $catID into database,but if i select them equally i.e TWO of $multID and TWO of $catID then it will work fine......please help solve this

i use this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID,nickID,avaID,multiID)VALUES(:postID,:catID,:multiID)');
foreach ($_POST['catID'] AS $i => $catID) {
    $multiID = $_POST['multiID'][$i];
    $stmt->execute(array(
                       ':postID' => $postID,
            ':catID' => $catID,

            ':multiID' => $multiID

                       ));
}
```

**and my form looks ike this**

```
<form action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>

<p><label>Title</label><br />
<input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>
<br/><br/>
 <?php    
$checked = null;
$stmt3 = $db->query('SELECT multiID, multiTitle FROM multi_image ORDER BY multiID');
while($row3 = $stmt3->fetch()){
    if(isset($_POST['multiID'])){
        if(in_array($row3['multiID'], $_POST['multiID'])){
           $checked="checked='checked'";
        }else{
           $checked = null;
        }
    }

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='multiID[]' value='".$row3['multiID']."' $checked> <img width='40px' src='upload/blog/".$row3['multiTitle']."'/><br />";
}
?>

<p><label>Content</label><br />
<textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?></textarea></p>

<fieldset>
<legend>Categories</legend>

<?php    
$checked = null;

$stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
    if(isset($_POST['catID'])){
        if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
           $checked="checked='checked'";
        }else{
           $checked = null;
        }
    }

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
}
?>
</fieldset>

<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

</form>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `$multiID = $multiID;` to do? It doesn't do anything, it just assigns a variable to itself.

Comment: How do you set `$multiID` before you do `if(is_array($multiID))`? It's probably not a good idea to use the same variable as the iteration variable of the loop. You have the same problem with `$catID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over one of the arrays, and then use the index to access the corresponding element of the other array.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog (postID,catID,multiID)VALUES(:postID,:catID,:multiID)');
foreach ($_POST['catID'] AS $i => $catID) {
    $multiID = $_POST['multiID'][$i];
    $stmt->execute(array(
                       ':postID' => $postID,
                       ':catID' => $catID,
                       ':multiID' => $multiID
                       ));
}
```

Notice that you only need to prepare the statement once, not every time through the loop.

Comment: thank you @barmar ,i have tried your solution ,it works but not properly,the two checkbox **$multID** and **$catID** works fine only if i select them equally. what i meant is this -----> if i select TWO item from **$multID** and select ONE item from **$catID** it will INSERT just ONE item of **$multiD**  bcos i select just one of **$catID** into database,but if i select them equally i.e TWO of **$multID** and TWO of  **$catID** then it will work......please help solve this

Comment: Right, I forgot that these are checkboxes.

Comment: Can you update the question and show what the HTML looks like, and what should be inserted into the database depending on how the boxes are checked.

Comment: You still haven't explained what should be put into the database. If they check more than one `catID` or `multiID`, how do these get put into the table?

Comment: `blog (postID,catID,multiID)`.....`blog` is a table that collect id's of two tables **category** and **multiImage** whenever th boxes where checked . `$catID` is a id of table **category*` , and `$multiID` is a id of another table **multiImage** ,if these checkboxes are clicked the id's of these row **catID[category] and multiID[mutiImage]** will submit into blog table...the id's where not submited properly unless they are selected equally.

Comment: Please add all these details to the question, not a comment. But I find it hard to understand your explanations. Show specific examples and what the expected result in the database should be.